# how to preserve signature on react with useRef

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-signature-canvas for Signature Pad but signature disappear after i close and reopen the modal. is there a possible way to preserve the signature on the modal after its closed ?

i've tried by initializing useRef() on higher component and passing to Modal component

**Expected behavior**

signature to preserve on modal close

I created [this live running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-torvalds-uykjb) to illustrate the problem:

Any feedback about this issue ?

Comment: i have not looked at your example.... But in react the common pattern would be to keep state in a "store" and use a reducer to change that state and query that store to get the state etc.... You should look at Redux/Saga or some other form of state machine like MobX

Comment: So it looks like the signature component has an `onEnd` function. You'd have to use that in conjunction with the ref's API to store the drawn signature when they stop drawing. Basically, when you call `onEnd` you store the signature they drew in the state of the parent using the `ref.current.toData()` method. Then, when opening the modal, if they've drawn one before (you can set state to null initially and check for that) then you can use the `ref.current.fromData(signatureState)` method to draw the signature

Comment: any chance you've updated the example with the solution below? it is a bit confusing that the issue doesn't reproduced on the example....

Comment: @eplaut i've updated the example with solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to store signature data on save. And set the initial state of SignaturePad on handleClickOpen. Something like this

```
  const [pointsArray, setPointsArray] = React.useState(null);
  const save = () => {
    setPointsArray(sigCanvas.current.toData());
    setImageURL(sigCanvas.current.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL("image/png"));
  };
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (pointsArray) {
        sigCanvas.current.fromData(pointsArray);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: How do you get this to work with typescript?